# How to render HTML into a variable programmatically

Tags: theming, 8

Let's assume you have a "product" node `$node`, and for some reason you want to render HTML from $node into a variable $html using a Twig template. I'm a bit desperate yet, what would you do?

Additional info 1: We are not in a controller, but in a simple class that is registered as a service.

Additional info 2: [4k4 's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223507/70812) does work if I call my class from a controller. But as soon I call it from a Drupal Console command I get an Exception "The theme implementations may not be rendered until all modules are loaded."

**Edit: The complete solution**

Obviously not all modules are loaded if we call the service inside a Drupal Console command. The Theme Manager will honor this with the aforementioned exception, so we have to force load the modules:

```
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->loadAll(); // Load all modules if not loaded already
```

Now it's safe to call the renderPlain() method as suggested below:

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode, $langcode);
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

**Edit: But what about a full page?**

If you intend to render not only the node content but a full page (from `<html>` to `</html>`) you have to have the kernel handle an appropriate sub-request .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To render a plain node view, for example for emails, use this code:

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode, $langcode);
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

If you want to customize the output, use a special view mode and a template `node--[view-mode].html.twig`.

**Edit: Full page**

You can build more complex render arrays:

```
  $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
  $content = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode, $langcode);
  $build = [
    '#type' => 'html',
    'page' => [
      '#type' => 'page',
      '#theme' => 'page',
      '#title' => 'Title',
      'content' => $content,
    ],
  ];

  $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

This is only a basic version of a page, if you want the full version with all features like attachments and libraries you need a request on Drupal.

Comment: I am getting an Exception: "The theme implementations may not be rendered until all modules are loaded". I have seen this many times today. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that my code is called by a console command, but I'm totally stuck here.

Comment: Ok, tested it, it just works if I call it from a controller. But how can I do the same in a console command?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do, but just dropped it in a drush script and it works.

Comment: Not to use drush is a project requirement, I have to use drupal/console instead. I hope it is just an incompatibility between the current console (1.0.0-rc11) and core (8.2.4) versions.

Comment: Figured it out, pls see the "complete solution" section above.