# Render a view in a given language in a custom command

Tags: 8, console

I have written a Drupal Console command that creates a huge batch of HTML snippets. This is done by rendering a view programmatically (as in [this StackExchange answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/223505/70812))

**The task**

Now I have to create these snippets in several languages.

**This works**

If I call the view in my browser I can easily chose the language with the respective path prefix:

http://www.example.com/de/path/to/the/view (german version)

http://www.example.com/en/path/to/the/view (english version)

**This does not work**

If I try to render the very same view from a Drupal Console command I am not able to set the target language. The rendered HTML is always in the default language.

At first I thought passing the langcode in the view() method should suffice:

```
// Now render the node as HTML
$viewBuilder = $this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder('node');
$build       = $viewBuilder->view($node, 'full', $langcode);
$html        = $this->renderer->renderPlain($build);
```

Then I tried setConfigOverrideLanguage():

```
$this->languageManager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);

// … render the view here …

$this->languageManager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($originalLanguage);
```

But this did not work either. So it tried:

```
$this->configFactory->getEditable('system.site')->set('langcode', $langcode)->save();

// … render the view here …

$this->configFactory->getEditable('system.site')->set('langcode', $originalLangcode)->save();
```

But I did not succeed. I even tried [using a custom LanguageNegotiator](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/216051), but I ran into a fatal error due to the fact that the service 'language_manager' does not implement the ConfigurableLanguageManagerInterface, so it is missing the setNegotiator() and getNegotiator() methods.

Once again I am totally stuck and I don't know what I am missing (most likely just a tiny bit). How in the world is it possible to change the language of my rendered HTML???

**Edit 2017-01-05:**

I have to admit I am quite desperate atm. I even tried everything I ruled out above again. Guess what, it still does not work. Any ideas? I am so shure that I am missing only a tiny piece. But I don't have any idea where to search for :(

**Edit 2017-01-17:**

Obviously the console command is not aware of (parts of) the context, even if I set the language. Just to get it done I am considering putting together a request object which I would then have been handled by the kernel. If this should turn out to be too complicated I could still curl the respective pages, but I have a feeling that there should be another way of doing this.

**Edit 2017-03-14:**

First of all there there has to be a translation (even if the node data is in no way language specific). If you want the complete context you have to use the Kernel's `handle` method with a sub request.

Comment: Your second attempt with `setConfigOverrideLanguage` should have worked. have a look at [this answer by @Gábor Hojtsy on StackExchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202483/programatically-render-a-node-in-a-specific-language). You can temporarily change the language from the container.

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
Drupal::service("entity_field.manager")->clearCachedFieldDefinitions();
```

after language changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are referring to a view mode or a view (as in views module). If it's about a view mode:

> $ ddev drush si demo_umami --yes

> $ ddev drush php:cli

```
$node = Node:load(2);
$langcode = 'es';
$translation = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
$build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($translation, 'full', $langcode);
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

Renders in Spanish:

```
[...]
<a href="/es/recipes/bizcochos-veganos-de-chocolate-y-nueces" rel="bookmark">\n
[...]
```