# How do I capture a page as HTML?

Tags: theming, 8, page-controller

I have a controller that generates a custom 500 page.  I have set up a route at the path: '/500'.  I would like to capture this as HTML and save as a static file, so that I don't need to bootstrap Drupal and run that controller when I return a custom 500 page.

I have been using this code:

```
  global $base_url;

  $contents = file_get_contents($base_url . "/500");
```

This works for me locally, but we have a lot of restrictions on our QA site so that [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is blocked.

Is there another way to render the entire page that this controller would return?  For example, with the render service?

Also, I would want it in a logged-out context.  I wouldn't want the admin toolbars, etc. to show up.

I found some code about subroutines.  Is that a good way?  I'm sure there's a way to use the Drupal render service to render a render array with the entire page.  That sounds maybe the best way to do this?

Does anyone know how I might render the entire page programmatically?

I'm thinking in order to render the metadata and page classes based on a route, you're pretty much required to make a request.

There is another question about [rendering parts of the page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223507/45409), but not the entire page.

Comment: By the way, I fixed the problem for myself by updating my vhost settings on the QA server to allow access from the same IP address.  Perhaps file_get_contents is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Does the page change very often? Otherwise, I would just save it once and commit the static HTML file to the repository.

Comment: Could you specify this file in Apache and point it to your static file for 500s?

Answer (score 0):

If you bootstrap Drupal, you can just tell it to serve a particular page. Consider the content of `index.php`:

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

If you replace the Request::createFromGlobals with a `new Request(...)`, you can pass explicit values for the `$_GET` etc parameters. The function signature copied from Symfony is as follows:

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param array           $query      The GET parameters
 * @param array           $request    The POST parameters
 * @param array           $attributes The request attributes (parameters parsed from the PATH_INFO, ...)
 * @param array           $cookies    The COOKIE parameters
 * @param array           $files      The FILES parameters
 * @param array           $server     The SERVER parameters
 * @param string|resource $content    The raw body data
 */
public function __construct(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), array $attributes = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null)
{
    $this->initialize($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
}
```

So your custom script could require the autoloader, bootstrap Drupal, create a fake Request object, tell Drupal to handle it, then save `$response->getContent()` to a file.